# Ktor parsing of arrays with nested objects config

Tags: ktor, typesafe-config, hocon

I am trying to use the following configuration in Ktor:

```
source {
  quotes {
    inputTopicBaseName = "quotes"
    providers = [
      {
        provider = "BHS"
        windows = [
          {
            grace = "PT1M"
            size = "PT1M"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        provider = "LSX"
        windows = [
          {
            grace = "PT1M"
            size = "PT1M"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  type = QUOTES
}
```

When I invoke `environment.config.config("source.quotes").configList("providers")`, it fails with the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" io.ktor.server.config.ApplicationConfigurationException: Property source.quotes.providers.size not found.
    at io.ktor.server.config.MapApplicationConfig.configList(MapApplicationConfig.kt:57)
    at io.ktor.server.config.MergedApplicationConfig.configList(MergedApplicationConfig.kt:37)
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5143) that will be fixed in Ktor 2.2.0.

Comment: Is there a workaround for now? Is there a way to access the config directly and use com.typesafe.config.Config for example?

Comment: Actually, it's working in 2.1.2, so I'll just use that instead of 2.1.3